# unable to create pandas dataframe from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to Pandas. I have two arrays var and esvar with 1000 values each. When I am trying to put it into a dataframe. I am getting one single row. I have tried transposing the matrices but still gives me the same result.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'VaR':[var],'ESVaR':[esvar]})
print(df)
```

Also tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'VaR':var[:,0],'ESVaR':esvar[:,1]})
print(df)
```

(This gives me too many indices error)

This is result from first one but I want the below in multiple rows and not one row.

```
VaR                                              ESVaR
0  [-0.10515868551869557, -0.11579987587576174, -...  [-0.09180443392815332, -0.10857606448322654, -...
```

Comment: Get rid of the square brackets around car and esvar.

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just drop the list symbols around your variables and you are good to go:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'VaR': var,'ESVaR': esvar})
```

Since `var` and `esvar` are already lists, your notation makes lists from lists and hence results in only one row in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Quang Hoang

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'VaR':var,'ESVaR':esvar})
print(df)
```